# Groupby two columns and find max count of categorical values in another column (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

**What is the Max count of values in the ‘stage’ column for a particular date.**  For the date of 2/1/2022, we see that the box AA holds the max count of the confidential value , which is 3.

**Data**

```
stage             box   Price   date
confidential      AA    $5,000  2/1/2022
confidential      AA    $5,050  2/1/2022
confidential      AA    $5,075  2/1/2022
confidential      BB    $5,116  2/1/2022
confidential      BB    $5,154  2/1/2022
nonconfidential   BB    $0      3/1/2022
```

**Desired**

Output I desire is the highest counts of 'confidential' value for a particular date.
Example we see that for the date of 2/1/2022, AA has the highest counts of the confidential string.

```
box   max_count   date

AA    3           2/1/2022
BB    1           3/1/2022
```

**Doing**

```
df.groupby(['box', 'date']).agg({'stage': 'size']}).reset_index()
```

I feel groupby and .agg is correct, however, I am not sure how to incorporate the max function. I am still researching.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Across which variable do you want the max? Your output suggests per date

Comment: Hi @mozway finding the max count of the value in the ‘stage’ column for that box and date

Comment: Then the desired output is incorrect. Where is the box BB?

Comment: Right I was showing the gist of it - BB would just be a single line - I will add

Comment: What is `stage` and `size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
out = (df
 .loc[df['stage'].eq('confidential')]
 .groupby(['box', 'date'], as_index=False)
 .agg(count=('stage', 'size'))
)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
  box      date  count
0  AA  2/1/2022      3
1  BB  2/1/2022      2
```

To get the max, you need a second `groupby` on date only:

```
out2 = out.loc[out.groupby('date')['count'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
  box      date  count
0  AA  2/1/2022      3
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway Essentially which box has the highest count for a particular date. Ex for 2/1/2022- so BB 2/1/2022 should not appear

Comment: Ok thank you - will try this - no way to avoid the first command?

Comment: @Lynn you could `pipe` both in a single command but this would lose in readability. The two steps are needed as you need the first aggregation as count to be able to compute the max (try the logic with pen and paper).

Comment: Ok will do this @mozway

Comment: hi, @mozway, I tried this, but when I print(out), I the count column is the only output - do I have to reset an index?

Comment: You have to print `out2`

Comment: Hi ,It won’t let me print out2 because out only displays the count column @mozway

Comment: Which pandas version du you have? Try the latest. Try also to remove `as_index=False` and use `reset_index` in the end.